# How can I place a one-column-abstract in a two-column document in Latex?

Tags: latex, overleaf

How can I place a one-column-table in two-column-section in a LaTeX template?

Comment: please add a [mre] to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your document is "short enuogh" to justify this approach, rather than the opposite, you can arrange part of the text on two columns using the environment [`multicols`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf) from the package [`multicol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Here the package `lipsum` is only to generate blind text content. The output:

[image: screenshot of output pdf]